# Why can I edit object by calling their methods but not referencing their variable names from within a smaller scope

Tags: python, scope

My main() function is:

```
def main():
    ...
    def _help():
        ...
1       a += somelist
2       a.append(something)

    a=[]
    _help()
```

What's weird is that *line 2* works perfectly fine, but *line 1* throws an `UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'a' referenced before assignment.`

Even when I declare `a` as a global variable at the top of either `main` or `_help`, it still doesn't work. Why is this?
Both of these lines are editing the same variable which makes me think either both or neither of them should work. How do I get *line 1* to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use `<variable> = <something>` in Python, Python automatically assumes it is a local variable, unless specifically told otherwise.

For example:

```
a = 1
def f():
    if False:
        a = 0
    print(a)  # UnboundLocalError
f()
```

In this case, `+=` works as assignment as well, but `.append` does not assign to `a`, but calls a method.

This is fixed by placing a `nonlocal a` in your function, so it can assign to the `a` outside of its scope:

```
def main():
    ...
    def _help():
        nonlocal a
        a += somelist  # Works!
```

But in this case, you can just do `a.extend(somelist)`.

Comment: how is nonlocal different from global?

Comment: @A-P `x = 7; def f(): def g(): nonlocal x; # x is undefined; it's looking for x within f(), but not in globals.` whereas `x = 7; def f(): def g(): global x;  # x == 7`.